# Добавление данных в БД с помощью php

Tags: php, mysql

Всегда выдает значение Упс

Я в php новичок

```html
<?php 
 // возможность добавить записи в "новости"
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['full_text'])){
$title=$_POST['title'];
$full_text=$_POST['full_text'];
}
$db_host = "localhost"; 
    $db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = 'animals'; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "news"; // Имя Таблицы БД

    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);


$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO news (`title`,`full_text`) VALUES ('".$title."','".$full_text."')");//добавления записи т.е. запись в БД
$res= mysqli_query($mysqli, $result); 
    if ($res == true){
     echo "Информация добавлена";
    }

  
    else 
    {
     echo 'Упс...';
}

?>
```

Comment: Используйте PDO

Comment: @zalex и чем пдо будет лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам запрос `query` необходимо указывать немного другим способом, если Вы выполняете в дальнейшем запрос.
В самой строке запроса можно не использовать дополнительное экранирование.
Так же добавил корректный вывод информации об ошибке, в случае если запрос не выполнен по какой-либо причине.
В этом случае Вы увидите соответствующую ошибку. 
Если запрос прошёл успешно, то будет выведена информация из БД.

```php
<?php
 // возможность добавить записи в "новости"
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['full_text'])){
$title=$_POST['title'];
$full_text=$_POST['full_text'];
}
$db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = 'animals'; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "news"; // Имя Таблицы БД

    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);


$result = "INSERT INTO news (`title`,`full_text`) VALUES ('$title','$full_text')";//добавления записи т.е. запись в БД
$res= mysqli_query($mysqli, $result);
if (!$result) {
    die('Ошибка выполнения запроса:' . mysqli_error()); // Если ошибка, запроса, то выводим имя ошибки.
}
// Если ошибки нет, то выводим данные

?>
```

Если необходимо отправлять запрос только в том случае, если получены оба данных.

```php
<?php
 // возможность добавить записи в "новости"
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['full_text'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $full_text = $_POST['full_text'];

    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
    $db_password = ""; // Пароль БД
    $db_base = 'animals'; // Имя БД
    $db_table = "news"; // Имя Таблицы БД

// Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_base);


    $result = "INSERT INTO news (`title`,`full_text`) VALUES ('$title','$full_text')";//добавления записи т.е. запись в БД
    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $result);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Ошибка выполнения запроса:' . mysqli_error()); // Если ошибка, запроса, то выводим имя ошибки.
    }
// Если ошибки нет, то выводим данные
    print_r($res);
}
```

Comment: а если какое-то поле пустое, как это реализовать? потому что сейчас отправляет даже с пустыми полями

Comment: @Evgeny_L Подскажите, что Вы имеете ввиду? Не отправлять поле, если оно пустое?

Comment: да, именно и это и имею ввиду, ну у меня есть форма там 2 поля и кнопка отправить, мне как это реализовать в форме прописать что обязательно чтобы было заполнено или это можно как-то через php сделать?

Comment: @Evgeny_L Вы можете это сделать в форме `html` указав полю аттрибут `required`. А так же добавить проверку в `php`. Добавил пример. В этом случае, запрос будет отправлен только, если эти данные получены из формы. Так же при необходимости дополнительно можно поставить проверку `!empty`.

Comment: а что по поводу передачи параметров в запрос? или и так сойдет?

Comment: @teran Что значит по поводу передачи данных? Что конкретно Вас не смущает уважаемый teran?

Comment: @teran В общем понятно. Вы, скорее всего даже не проверили ответ, а сказали наобум первое, что пришло в голову.  И такое бывает.

Comment: читаем информацию на тему "sql инъекции, подготовленные запросы, биндинг параметров".  и еще подумать по поводу отображения ошибок.

Comment: @teran Это тут вообще при чём??? Вы вопрос вообще читали? Пример автора смотрели?

Comment: а что вам мешает дать нормальный ответ? или абы какой сойдет?

Comment: @teran собственно, использование PDO - это бонус. Если бы автор ответа его использовал - было б отлично, но в таком виде тоже отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @teran Чем конкретно Вас не устроил ответ? Если бы я написал ответ с использованием предзапросов и PDO, то тоооочно такие же люди написали бы, что я слишком меняю ответ автора, что этого не было в вопросе. Уже проезжали такое, причём не однократно. Поинтересуйтесь у модераторов - менять формат ответа крайне не приветствуется. Как не стыдно, Вам лишь бы сделать замечание не в попад.

Comment: По факту вы выдали правильный ответ, но с другой стороны не было ни одного упоминания об `SQL` инъекции, что очень существенно может отразиться на работоспособности приложения. Ладно в коде нет об этом информации, но можно было это указать как пометку. Больше склоняюсь к мнению @teran .

Comment: во первых при чем тут пдо? по вторых я вам не предлагаю вообще переписывать код, но упомянуть об этом надо. я вот и упомянул в комментарии

Comment: @MoloF Используется `localhost` Это явно тестовый проект для обучения. О каких sql может идти речь используя локальный проект исключительно у себя на компьютере? Мне не сложно сделать пример на PDO - это 30 секунд, но я Вас уверяю, что минусов было бы ещё больше.

Comment: @teran Я не собираюсь с Вами дальше спорить. Вы совершенно не правы. Что явно демонстрирует Ваше отношение и тип агрессивности, который неоднократно обсуждали на форуме `en` stackoverflow. Доброго Вам вечера.

Comment: @Denis640Kb дело не в PDO, не в подготовленном запросе или простом `mysqli_real_escape_string`, дело в том, что вы не упомянули просто об этом. Я тоже разрабатываю локально проекты, это же не говорит о том, что я не буду это деплоить на прод, почему вы думаете что так не будет делать автор вопроса?

Comment: @AK Ответ был полностью дан в соответствии с вопросом. Нигде на сайте я не видел необходимости указывать предупреждения об sql инъекциях. И даже те товарищи, которые тут писали - САМИ свою очередь этого не делают в своих ответах. Это лишь личная неприязнь и желание испортить настроение, ничего более. Никакой практической пользы это не несёт. Вопрос не содержит просьбы помочь защитить подключение. Вопрос абсолютно конкретный и ответ на него дан соответствующий.